# How to get PR Curve in Object Detection API (Tensorflow)?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, precision-recall

Currently, I have a single object detection model trained for 1 class with a mAP score of 0.87, I trained it using the `model_main_tf2.py` script provided in TensorFlow.

Now I'm having a hard time setting the threshold when doing inference with this model. So after a little research, I understood that I need the Precision-Recall Curve so I can select the appropriate threshold depending on my application (precision-recall tradeoff). So far so good.

But now.. how can I get the PR Curve? After making validation, the only stuff that I get from the console is the mAP and AR values (from COCO detection metrics), but nothing else, even in tensorboard there's nothing showing PR-Curve (there is an option, but it shows empty).

I ran validation using the script provided in model_main_tf2.py, that is:

```
model_lib_v2.eval_continuously(
    pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_examples,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=(
        FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples
    ),
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir,
    wait_interval=300,
  )
```

I've already looked and found this  [PR Curve plugin](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/pr_curve), but the problem is that its only for image classification (not object detection, as I intend to)

On the other hand there is this [thread on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3081), but the code that's proposed in there seems from TensorFlow 1.

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction!

P.S1: In order to get the mAP values, the eval_continuisly(...) script should have already computed the PR Curve, so the calculation must be in some part of the code, but I cannot seem to find it, so I can print it out :S
P.S2: Maybe I should switch to YOLO? since object detection API is deprecated now :S